# How can I double a variable using class mutator in c++

Tags: c++

this is my first post, so sorry if I lack any etiquette. I'm trying to pass a Rectangle object by reference to a function, then double the dimensions using class mutators. I have no syntax errors, it seems I'm just calling the r.setWidth() and r.setHeight() mutators wrong. 
I was thinking this would work: r.setWidth(w * 2), but it doesn't. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;

Rectangle::Rectangle() { width = 1; height = 1; }
Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h) { width = w; height = h; }
Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}
int Rectangle::getWidth() { return width; }
int Rectangle::getHeight() { return height; }
void Rectangle::setWidth(int w) { width = w; }
void Rectangle::setHeight(int h) { height = h; }
int Rectangle::calculateArea() { return width * height; }

// end of Rectangle class implementation

void displayRectangle(Rectangle r);
void doubleAndDisplayRectangle(Rectangle& r);

int main()
{
    Rectangle r1, r2;
    int w, h; // temp width and height

    cout << "Please enter the width and height for the first rectangle: ";
    cin >> w >> h;
    r1.setWidth(w);
    r1.setHeight(h);

    cout << "Please enter the width and height for the second rectangle: ";
    cin >> w >> h;
    r2.setWidth(w);
    r2.setHeight(h);

    displayRectangle(r1);
    displayRectangle(r2);

    doubleAndDisplayRectangle(r1);
    doubleAndDisplayRectangle(r2);

    return 0;
}

void displayRectangle(Rectangle r)
{
    int w, h, area;
    cout << "Rectangle width = " << r.getWidth() << ", height = " << r.getHeight() << ", and area = " << r.calculateArea() << endl;
}

void doubleAndDisplayRectangle(Rectangle& r)
{
    int w, h, area;
    cout << "Doubling the rectangle dimensions!" << endl;
    /*r.setWidth(w)
    r.setHeight(h)*/
    cout << "Rectangle width = " << r.getWidth() << ", height = " << r.getHeight() << ", and area = " << r.calculateArea() << endl;
}
```

And here's my h file if needed.

```
#ifndef _RECTANGLE_H
#define _RECTANGLE_H

// declare the Rectangle class
class Rectangle
{
    private:
        int width = 0, height = 0;
    public:
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int w, int h);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getWidth();
        int getHeight();
        void setWidth(int w);
        void setHeight(int h);
        int calculateArea();
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question,  r.setWidth(w * 2), will not work because it does not  have any value affected. In other in your doubleAndDisplayRectangle function, w is simply a variable of type int. By default it has value zero.

You must first retreive the width of the rectangle passed by reference and multiply it by 2.

```
w=r.getWidth();
r.setWidth(w * 2); //this should work.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to double what its current value is then you need to use your *getters* to get that value so you can double it.

Something like this:

```
void doubleAndDisplayRectangle(Rectangle& r)
{
    cout << "Doubling the rectangle dimensions!" << endl;

    int current_width = r.getWidth(); // get current width

    r.setWidth(current_width * 2); // set it to double

    int current_height = r.getHeight(); // get current height

    r.setHeight(current_height * 2); // set it to double

    cout << "Rectangle width = " << r.getWidth() << ", height = " << r.getHeight() << ", and area = " << r.calculateArea() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Tip:*** - *Since you are new to C++ it is better to have the class's member declarations and definitions in their own header and cpp files respectively.
This makes it easier to compile that class for errors, and it also cleans up your main.cpp file.*

---

To answer your question as to why calling your `setters` with `::set( w * 2 )` will not work is that in your function that is modifying the rectangle you need to retrieve its dimensions before you can perform any mathematical operations on them.

When you were trying to call your function as such:

> ```
> void doubleAndDisplayRectangle( Rectangle& r ) {
>     int w, h, area;
>     cout << "Doubling the rectangle dimensions!" << endl;
>     /*r.setWidth(w)
>     r.setHeight(h)*/
>     cout << "Rectangle width = " << r.getWidth() << ", height = " << r.getHeight() << ", and area = " << r.calculateArea() << endl;
> }
> ```

The reason that `r.setWidth(2 * w);` wasn't working is that `w`, `h`, `area` are stack temporaries to that function and they are not even initialized so they could be storing any arbitrary number. If you look at my version of your function below you will see that I initialized them with the current size * 2.

```
int w = 2 * rec.widthOf();
int h = 2 * rec.heightOf();
```

Then I use `changeSize()` function to finally update the sizes

```
rec.changeSize( w, h );
```

In the comments of my function you can also see that this can be done in a single line:

```
rec.changeSize( 2 * rec.widthOf(), 2 * rec.heightOf() );
```

---

Here is what I have done along with a few modifications to your class:

- One of the changes I've made to your class are some of the function names; not a real big deal but instead of `getSomething` & `setSomething` it seems more intuitive to name them `somethingOf` & `changeSomething` instead.
- Any of the member functions that doesn't change anything but retrieves the class's member variables I've declared them as `const` methods.
- I added another variable to store the area and a member function to retrieve it.
- The methods that change the dimensions of the rectangle calls a member to automatically update its area.
- I added another function to be able to change both dimensions with a single function call.
- I added an overloaded `operator<<()` function to the class as a friend function. This makes outputing the `Rectangle` object much easier.
- As for the class's constructors I am using their initializer lists.
- I set the destructor to default since there is no memory allocation & freeing going on.
- I finally renamed the class to `MyRectangle` because my Visual Studio 2017 compiler on Windows 7 is fussy about user defined class named `Rectangle` that is in global scope.

I could have added the `doubleRectangleSize` to the class as well but chose to leave that as a stand alone function that takes in a reference to an object and makes a modification to it; this is where the `::changeSize(int, int)` comes in handy. The declaration of `doubleRectangleSize()` can be found in `Rectangle.h` and its definition or implementation is in `Rectangle.cpp` after all of the class's member functions. This function also no longer displays any information as you want to keep `calculations` separate from any display output.

---

Here you can check out what I've done:

**Rectangle.h**

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class MyRectangle {
private:
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
    int mArea;
public:
    MyRectangle();
    MyRectangle( int width, int height );
    ~MyRectangle() = default;

    int widthOf() const;
    int heightOf() const;
    int areaOf() const;

    void changeWidth( int width );
    void changeHeight( int height );
    void changeSize( int width, int height );

    int calculateArea();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const MyRectangle& rec );
};

void doubleRectangleSize( MyRectangle& rec );

#endif // !RECTANGLE_H
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

MyRectangle::MyRectangle() :
  mWidth( 0 ),
  mHeight( 0 ),
  mArea( 0 ) {
}

MyRectangle::MyRectangle( int width, int height ) :
 mWidth( width ),
 mHeight( height ) {
    mArea = calculateArea();
}

int MyRectangle::widthOf() const {
    return mWidth;
}

int MyRectangle::heightOf() const {
    return mHeight;
}

int MyRectangle::areaOf() const {
    return mArea;
}

void MyRectangle::changeWidth( int width ) {
    if ( width < 0 ) { // Invalid Dimension Size
        return; 
    }
    if ( width != mWidth ) { // Only do this if there is a change in dimension size
        mWidth = width;
        mArea = calculateArea(); // Need to update the change in area
    }
}

void MyRectangle::changeHeight( int height ) {
    if ( height < 0 ) { // Invalid Dimension Size
        return;
    } 
    if ( height != mHeight ) { // Only do this if there is a change in dimension size
        mHeight = height;
        mArea = calculateArea(); // Need to update the change in area
    }
}

void MyRectangle::changeSize( int width, int height ) {
    if ( width < 0 || height < 0 ) { // either width or height invalid
        return;
    }

    bool changeInSize = false;

    if ( width != mWidth ) {
        mWidth = width;
        changeInSize = true;
    }

    if ( height != mHeight ) {
        mHeight = height;
        changeInSize = true;
    }

    if ( changeInSize ) {
        mArea = calculateArea();
    }
}

int MyRectangle::calculateArea() {
    return mWidth * mHeight;
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const MyRectangle& rec ) {
    out << "Width = " << rec.mWidth << ", Height = " << rec.mHeight
        << ", Area = " << rec.mArea << std::endl;
    return out;
}

void doubleRectangleSize( MyRectangle& rec ) {
    int w = 2 * rec.widthOf();
    int h = 2 * rec.heightOf();
    rec.changeSize( w, h );

    // You can also do it like this in a single line without using temp stack variables:
    // rec.changeSize( 2 * rec.WidthOf(), 2 * rec.HeightOf() ); 
}
```

Now with this class and function being in their own header and cpp file your main will look as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // only used for _getch() to stop visual studio's debugging console from closing
#include "Rectangle.h"

int main() {
    MyRectangle r1, r2;
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter the width & height for the first rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> w >> h;
    r1.changeSize( w, h );

    std::cout << "Please enter the width & height for the second rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> w >> h;
    r2.changeSize( w, h );

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First Rectangle:\n" << r1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second Rectangle:\n" << r2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Doubling the rectangle dimenions:\n";
    doubleRectangleSize( r1 );
    std::cout << "First Rectangle:\n" << r1 << std::endl;
    doubleRectangleSize( r2 );
    std::cout << "Second Rectangle:\n" << r2 << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Now when I run this program and use the following values as inputs (2,4) & (5,7) for the two rectangles respectively I get this following output:

> Please enter the width & height for the first rectangle: 2 4
>   Please enter the width & height for the second rectangle: 5 7
>
> First Rectangle:
>   Width = 2, Height = 4, Area = 8
>
> Second Rectangle:
>   Width = 5, Height = 7, Area = 35
>
> Doubling the rectangle dimensions:
>   First Rectangle:
>   Width = 4, Height = 8, Area = 32
>
> Second Rectangle:
>   Width = 10, Height = 14, Area = 140

---

The functions are bounds safe & efficient what I mean by this is if you use any of the functions to change any dimensions size of the rectangle it will check to see first if the value is valid `s > 0` if it is negative an invalid entry the function will return, If the value is 0 it is acceptable however the area will be 0. Next it will check if there is a change in size of the dimension; if they are equal nothing happens saving you instructions calls, but if there is a change it will update that dimension and it will also automatically update its area based on that change.

---

This should help you along your way.